# WiFi Hard blocked: yes

Tags: debian, fedora, linux-mint, wifi-configuration, asus-laptop

WiFi PCI (and USB) adapters are not available on my system - Asus Laptop F55 / Linux Mint 17.1 (Ralink rt2800pci)

Debian, Ubuntu or Fedora 21 have the same problem with my configuration.

Any clue on how to make it on and available? It is working fine on Windows 8.1, Linux Crunchbang Waldorf.

http://dpaste.com/2WD2W23

**sudo rfkill list**

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing your driver rt2800 is already installed, you are using an Asus Notebook and  key combination are not providing any results.

Solution found :

Create or edit an Asus configuration file in /etc/modprobe.d/ directory to enable WLAN at boot up. Modprobe is interacting with the device manager for the Linux kernel during the system boot. Add a line in order to activate Asus Notebooks WMI hotkey driver (asus-nb-wmi) : set wapf value to 4, it will enable asus-nb-wmi.

1. Run this command on the terminal :

   **gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf**
2. Add this line :

   options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4
3. Reboot and check your wifi management interface. Your wlan features should be available.

*Sources :*

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1172151/comments/41

http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/1404.2/04051.html